# conformal mappings of Riemann sphere

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

We know that Möbius transformations are the conformal selfmaps of the Riemann sphere.

But what does being conformal at infinity correspond to?what does it mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A complex function $f(z)$ is conformal at infinity if the function $f(1/z)$ is conformal at 0. This equivalent to the usual definition of conformal in terms of leaving angles unchanged in size and sense (clockwise/anticlockwise) if you think of $f$ as being conformal at infinity if it leaves angles unchanged at the "North Pole" of the Riemann sphere.

For example, if you take the function $f(z)=\displaystyle\frac{1}{z+1}$, then $f(1/z) = \displaystyle\frac{1}{1/z+1} = \frac{z}{1+z}$. which is conformal at 0, so that $f(z)$ is conformal at infinity.